# how to align icons bootstrap menu (in collapsed state)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code

```
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="banner">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
                    <h1><img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo"></h1>
                </a>

            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-2x fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-2x fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-2x fa-youtube-play"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

When I run it in normal mode - it does this..

[image]

but when I go into mobile mode - the icons get weirdly aligned.

It becomes like so

[image]

How can I make it so the icons are aligned left or right in the mobile mode (when it gets collapsed)

Answer (score 1):

This is what you are looking for

```css
.navbar-brand img{
  max-height: 100%;
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      
                    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2f/Google_2015_logo.svg/1000px-Google_2015_logo.svg.png" alt="logo">
                </a>
      
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-youtube-play"></i></a></li>
      </ul>
      
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: your code does not collapse. I want it to collapse. If I use text instead of font-awesome - it aligns correctly - but If I use font-awsome it comes that weird state. I would like for it to collapse in mobile mode - but also align.

Comment: @hypermails I updated my answer, here is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/murhafsousli/vet9v0f7/) too

Answer (score 0):

I don't find any problem check the snippet, if you want to show the url I can check it.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="banner">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
                    <h1 style="padding:0px;margin:0px;line-height:20px;;"><img src="http://scholar.google.it/intl/it/scholar/images/1x/googlelogo_color_270x104dp.png" style="height:40px;" alt="logo"></h1>
                </a>

            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-2x fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-2x fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-2x fa-youtube-play"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```